# Кастомизация заголовка экрана (react native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Есть компонент для хэдера экрана мобильного устройства

```js
function CustomTitle(props) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems:"space-between"}}>
      <Text style={{flex:1}}>{props.name}</Text>
      <Text style={{flex:3}}>{props.number}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Здесь функция для вставки в заголовок значения, который прилетает из переменной `route`

```js
const [title, setTitle] = useState(route.params.name);
const [titleNumber, steTitleNumber] = useState(route.params.number);

React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
  navigation.setOptions({
    title:
      title === "" ? (
        "No title"
      ) : (
        <CustomTitle name={title} number={titleNumber} />
      ),
  });
}, [navigation, title]);
```

Вопрос заключается в банальной верстке. Как `Text` блок, который содержит `name` оставить по середине хэдера, а второй текстовый блок с `number` прижать к правому краю. В данный момент оба элемента распологаются по центру и общий стиль `alignItems` не отрабатывает

Так это выглядит, а я хочу, чтобы все после решетки ушло в правый край
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение. Вот [здесь](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/) нашел использование `setOptions` с параметром `headerRight` для добавления кнопки. И вот [здесь](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#headerright) можно найти описание функции. Если туда помещается кнопка, значит уж текст точно влезет. Пробуем:

```js
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
  navigation.setOptions({
    headerRight:()=>(
        <CustomTitle number={titleNumber} />
      ),
      title: title
  });
}, [navigation, title, titleNumber]);
```

Теперь `title` ставится на прямую в `title`, а в правую сторону только значения `number`.

Элемент, который улетает вправо реализован так:

```js
function CustomTitle(props) {
  return (
      <Text style={{ color:colors.white, marginEnd:10}}>{props.number}</Text>
  );
}
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]